# Annoying long equations in LaTeX

Tags: equations, amsmath, subequations

I am giving up on this long and annoying equation. I tried in so many different ways to try to fit into my page, but no success so far...Any suggestions, please? How to break down this long equation and fit into my page?

Here is my equation:

```
\begin{align}
\delta _{E}^{2}(\textbf{u})=E\left \{Z^{*}(\textbf{u})-Z(\textbf{u})\right\}
=E\left \{[Z^{*}(\textbf{u})^2]  \right \}-2\cdot E\left \{Z ^{*}(\textbf{u})\cdot Z(\textbf{u})  \right \} +E\left \{ [Z(\textbf{u})]^2 \right \}
=\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }E\left \{ Z(\textbf{u}_{\alpha })\cdot Z(\textbf{u}_{\beta}) \right \}-2\cdot\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n} \lambda _{\alpha }E\left \{ Z(\textbf{u})\cdot Z(\textbf{u}_{\alpha }) \right \}+C(0)
=C(0)-2\cdot \sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }C(\textbf{u},\textbf{u}_{\alpha})+\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }C
(\textbf{u}_{\alpha}\textbf{u}_{\beta)}
\end{align}
```

Comment: I've edited your syntax highlighting, but the `%\end{align}` is wrong. As well as `\textbf{..}`

Comment: I have made a mistake and guess deleted your edited code accidentally..apologies.

Comment: You're not using a single feature of the `align` environment actually

Comment: that "align" gives you--the equation(s) to be numbered, let's say if you have more than one equation and they are linked to each other i.e. 1.1, 1.2...1.n?

Comment: @Sally7874 you should only use `align` if you have alignment points (`&`) just use `equation` for a single equation. Your question would be much clearer if you provided a complete small document (as in Christian's answer) in particular you ask to make it fit into the page without saying how wide the page is.

Comment: The code posted would not make the image shown, there are no `\\ ` so it would be single line, or has it been corrupted during posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a variant solution, based on `flalign`, that fits all equations on one line. I removed some unnecessary (from my point of view) `\cdots`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
      \mathrlap{ \delta _{E}^{2}(\mathbf{u})=E\left \{Z^{*}(\mathbf{u})-Z(\mathbf{u})\right\}}\\
     & & & =E\left \{[Z^{*}(\mathbf{u})^2] \right \}-2\, E\left \{Z ^{*}(\mathbf{u})\cdot Z(\mathbf{u}) \right \} +E\left \{ [Z(\mathbf{u})]^2 \right \} \\
      & & & =\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }E\left \{ Z(\mathbf{u}_{\alpha })\cdot Z(\mathbf{u}_{\beta}) \right \}-2\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n} \lambda _{\alpha }E\left \{ Z(\mathbf{u})\cdot Z(\mathbf{u}_{\alpha }) \right \}+C(0) \\
      & & & =C(0)-2\smash[t]{ \sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}}\lambda _{\alpha }C(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}_{\alpha})+\smash[t]{\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }C(\mathbf{u}_{\alpha}\mathbf{u}_{\beta})
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using `align` with `\\` will improve the look, but the 3rd equation is still too wide.

Using `split` within `align` will improve that 3rd. equation as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\tbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\delta _{E}^{2}(\tbf{u})& =E\left \{Z^{*}(\tbf{u})-Z(\tbf{u})\right\}\\
&=E\left \{[Z^{*}(\tbf{u})^2]  \right \}-2\cdot E\left \{Z ^{*}(\tbf{u})\cdot Z(\tbf{u})  \right \} +E\left \{ [Z(\tbf{u})]^2 \right \} \\
&=\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }E\left \{ Z(\tbf{u}_{\alpha })\cdot Z(\tbf{u}_{\beta}) \right \}-2\cdot\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n} \lambda _{\alpha }E\left \{ Z(\tbf{u})\cdot Z(\tbf{u}_{\alpha }) \right \}+C(0) \\
&=C(0)-2\cdot \sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }C(\tbf{u},\tbf{u}_{\alpha})+\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }C(\tbf{u}_{\alpha}\tbf{u}_{\beta)}
\end{align}

    \begin{align}
\delta _{E}^{2}(\tbf{u})& =E\left \{Z^{*}(\tbf{u})-Z(\tbf{u})\right\}\\
&=E\left \{[Z^{*}(\tbf{u})^2]  \right \}-2\cdot E\left \{Z ^{*}(\tbf{u})\cdot Z(\tbf{u})  \right \} +E\left \{ [Z(\tbf{u})]^2 \right \} \\
\begin{split}\label{somelabel}
 & =\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }E\left \{ Z(\tbf{u}_{\alpha })\cdot Z(\tbf{u}_{\beta}) \right \} \\
 & \quad -2\cdot\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n} \lambda _{\alpha }E\left \{ Z(\tbf{u})\cdot Z(\tbf{u}_{\alpha }) \right \}+C(0) \\
\end{split} \\
&=C(0)-2\cdot \sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }C(\tbf{u},\tbf{u}_{\alpha})+\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }C(\tbf{u}_{\alpha}\tbf{u}_{\beta)}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `split` should be used

Comment: why `\text{\textbf` (`\textbf` would be the same but quicker , but I'd use `\mathbf` which is much quicker, and semantically purer, I think)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I rarely use `\mathbf`, actually, but I've changed it in the wrapper.

Comment: Hey Christian, thanks for your suggestions! Another quick question: When I use (align*) the entire equation is got numbered where it was split, but that is not what I wanted...I just want to number once the whole equation, let's say 3.1, not 3.1 ...3.2...and so on. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Sally7874: You're changing the question. And `align*` will not number the equation, unless you use `\tag` explicitly.

Comment: In the attached image of my equation it is numbered as 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7, but that is not what I wanted. I just want to number that equation once as 3.4, and that is it.. That was my question. Thanks

Comment: @Sally7874 your question doesn't even mention numbering!

Comment: Not at all your fault, but the positioning of that C(0) gives the unfortunate first impression of an out of alignment - and out of sequence - equation number

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think you should use `split` for the whole thing.

Comment: The very last `)` symbol is misplaced.

Comment: @Mico: Either a typo or just used from O.P.

Comment: @egreg: Perhaps, but I leave that to the O.P.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to tell LaTeX where the line breaks should occur and where on each line alignment should take place. In the example at hand, alignment should probably happen on the four `=` symbols, right?

Some suggestions to make the material a bit more compact so that even the longest line fits inside the available space:

- Omit the `\cdot` directives -- they take up a lot of space and, frankly, aren't needed for legibility.
- Load the `mleftright` package and issue the instruction `\mleftright` in the preamble. That way, the extra whitespace to the left of each `\left` directive and to the right of each `\right` directive is suppressed. Alternatively, you could simply omit all six `\left` and all six `\right` directives, since the curly braces they apply to don't need to be enlarged in the first place.

Some additional suggestions:

- Do arrange the elements in the third equation so that they correspond more naturally to those in the second and fourth equation.
- Since `E` is an operator, it should be set in an upright font shape. See the code below for an implementation of this idea.
- Use `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf` in math mode.
- Do fix the misplaced position of the very last `)` symbol in the final line: It should be `... \mathbf{u}_{\beta})` instead of `...\mathbf{u}_{\beta)}`, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\usepackage{mleftright}\mleftright
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\delta_{\E}^{2}(\mathbf{u})
&= \E\left\{ Z^{*}(\mathbf{u})-Z(\mathbf{u})\right\} \\
&= \E\left\{ [Z^{*}(\mathbf{u})^2] \right\}-2 \E\left\{ Z ^{*}(\mathbf{u}) Z(\mathbf{u}) \right\} +\E\left\{ [Z(\mathbf{u})]^2 \right\} \\
&= C(0)-2\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n} \lambda_{\alpha}\E\left\{ Z(\mathbf{u}) Z(\mathbf{u}_{\alpha}) \right\} +\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}\lambda_{\alpha}\lambda_{\beta } \E\left\{ Z(\mathbf{u}_{\alpha}) Z(\mathbf{u}_{\beta}) \right\} \\
&= C(0)-2 \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}\lambda_{\alpha}C(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}_{\alpha}) +\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}\sum_{\beta=1}^{n} \lambda_{\alpha}\lambda_{\beta}  C(\mathbf{u}_{\alpha}\mathbf{u}_{\beta})
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the [breakeqn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn?lang=en) package. You enclose the equation in the dmath environment. The package should be loaded after other packages dealing with maths, e.g., amsmath, amssymb, or packages such as mathpazo or mathptmx.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% The breqn package should come after any maths packages.
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
% Like the equation environment but the dmath environment allows for line breaking.
\begin{dmath}
\delta_{E}^{2}(\textbf{u})=E\left \{Z^{*}(\textbf{u})-Z(\textbf{u})\right\}
=E\left \{[Z^{*}(\textbf{u})^2]  \right \}-2\cdot E\left \{Z ^{*}(\textbf{u})\cdot Z(\textbf{u})  \right \} +E\left \{ [Z(\textbf{u})]^2 \right \}
=\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\sum_{\beta =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }E\left \{ Z(\textbf{u}_{\alpha })\cdot Z(\textbf{u}_{\beta}) \right \}-2\cdot\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n} \lambda _{\alpha }E\left \{ Z(\textbf{u})\cdot Z(\textbf{u}_{\alpha }) \right \}+C(0)
=C(0)-2\cdot \sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }C(\textbf{u},\textbf{u}_{\alpha})+\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}\lambda _{\alpha }\lambda _{\beta }C(\textbf{u}_{\alpha}\textbf{u}_{\beta)}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

The package should automate line breaking for you.